# Unable to connect to expo xde using expo client on local network

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I need help about expo xde.
After creating project, when I scan QR Code it is giving me following error:

```
there was a problem loading the experience. It looks like you may be using a LAN url. 
Make sure your device is on same network as server or try using a tunnel

exp://*.*.*.*:19000
Error Code: NETWORK_ERROR
Code: -1004
```

My mobile device is on same network as my laptop.I am using:

```
OS: window 10
Node Version: 8.9.4
NPM Version: 4.6.1
```

It works on tunnel connection but it is bit slow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error means the mobile device can not connect to the development server running on your laptop.

Possible reasons for this include:

- Your mobile device and laptop are not connected to the same LAN (local area network).
- The network/router doesn't allow devices to connect to each other.
- Your laptop has a firewall that is blocking connections to the development server port (in this case port 19000).
- Your laptop has multiple network interfaces and the LAN URL points to a different one than that the mobile device can connect to.

To fix this you could:

- Use the tunnel URL that is slower, but works even if the device can't connect through LAN.
- Change firewall settings / use a different network.
- Connect your laptop to your mobile hotspot.
- If you have multiple network interfaces and XDE shows the IP address of a wrong one, you can use [Expo CLI](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/exp-cli.html) and set the correct IP with the `EXPO_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME` environment variable. (On Windows) you can alternatively [adjust the priority of your network adapters](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/adapter-priority-setting-unavailable-in-windows-10/d2b63caa-e77c-4b46-88b5-eeeaee00c306).
- (Android only) Install Android developer tools, plug your Android device to your laptop via USB and ensure [USB debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#device-developer-options) is enabled. Expo developer tools automatically run `adb reverse`, which makes the device able to connect via USB using the `localhost` URL.

Comment: thanks @fson
there was adapter priority issue between two networks on my laptop. solved this issue by following commands on this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/adapter-priority-setting-unavailable-in-windows-10/d2b63caa-e77c-4b46-88b5-eeeaee00c306

Comment: Thank you for letting us know how you solved the issue. I've updated my answer to include this case too.